# CSS position absolute content area not growing

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I am trying to create an HTML of a design. I am stuck with one issue.
The CSS n HTML structure is as an image that i have attached here.
I want the footer to be in the bottom of the page where the content area when grows should push the footer down. But if there is no content the content area should be till the footer.
actually the content area is coming over the header and footer area.
i don't know if i structured it right.

[image]

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<style>
html, body { height:100%;}
body {
    background: #EBEBEB;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:147px;
    background:#999;
    border-bottom:solid 5px #ddd;
    position:absolute;
}
#footer {
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:170px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#ccc;
    border-top:solid 5px #ddd;
}
#contentArea {
    width:300px;
    max-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:120px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
</style
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
    <div id="contentArea">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

check the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/angel3m/CDeLe/12/).

Comment: May I ask why you have your html's structure as header and footer first before content?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `magrin` for that!
and an advice:  use `postition:relative;` for your main sections!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    *{
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #header,#footer{
        position:relative;
        height:150px;
        background:#ccc;
        border:solid 1px #bbb;
    }
    #footer{
        bottom:0;
    }
    #body{
        position:relative;
        margin-top:-50px;
        margin-bottom:-50px;
        min-height:250px;
        background:#aaa;
        width:70%;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        padding:50px 15px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px #aaa;
        border:solid 1px #999;
        opacity:0.92;
        z-index:999;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='header'>
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div id='body'>
        BODY
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>
        FOOTER
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/2zfjc/

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues with the margins:

```
#contentArea {
    margin-top:152px;
    margin-bottom:175px;
}
```

If you do the math, the header height is 147px plus 5px for the border. The footer height is 170px plus 5px for the border. Since you are using absolute positioning, everything is set relative to the nearest positioned parent which is the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;    
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0; }
            .header {
                height: 140px;
                width: 100%;
                background: #999;
                border-bottom: solid 5px #ddd; }
            .content {
                height: calc(100% - 280px);
                width: 100%;
                background: #EBEBEB; }
            .content-fixed {
                position: fixed;
                height: auto;
                width: 300px;
                top: 90px;
                left: calc(50% - 150px);
                border: 1px solid red;
                background-color: #FFF;
            }
            .footer {
                height: 140px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #ccc;
                border-top: solid 5px #ddd; }        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content-fixed">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LOLKFC/vMz5s/

Answer (score 0):

i have add a new div on the foot of the container and make it on absolute and add a new css.

for the new css:

```
html, body { height:100%;}
body {
    background: #EBEBEB;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*margin: 0 auto; when you make the width 100% the margin auto is useless */
    position:relative;
}
#header, #footer {
    width:100%;
    height:147px;
    background:#999;
    border-bottom:solid 5px #ddd;
}
#contentArea {
    margin: -30px auto;
width: 300px;
background: #FFF;
border: solid 1px red;
position: relative;
}
#contentArea .containerFooter{
    width: 300px;
height: 0px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: #fff;
}
```

for the new HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="contentArea">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
        <div class="containerFooter"></div></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

look at my update  http://jsfiddle.net/CDeLe/62/

Answer (score 0):

Well,

here is the right code that i wanted.

```
    html, body { height:100%;}
body { height:100%; margin: 0px;}
#wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-30px;
}
#content {
    background:#ebebeb;
    width:450px;
    height: 100%;
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:20;
    top:-15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #666;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/angel3m/h6YYa/